# exported excel sheet has no .xls file extension in Mozilla

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS 2008,C#.net,asp.net.
I am exporting the data to excel 2003.
The exported excel is of the type .xls in IE and Chrome.
But it is not .xls type in mozilla.When open that file, it is asking which program you want to open?
What is the reason?

the program is mentioned below.
 ## Heading ##

private void ExportDataSetToExcel()
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable DT = new DataTable();

```
            string param = hidType.Get("Type").ToString();
            string[] codes = param.Split('.');
            if (codes.Length == 1)
                FillGrid(Convert.ToString(param));
            else
                FillDrillDownGrid(codes[1], codes[0]);
            if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "2")
            {
                DT.Columns.Add("<b>Sub Group Code</b>");
                DT.Columns.Add("<b>Account Sub Group</b>");
            }
            else if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "3")
            {
                DT.Columns.Add("<b>Group Code</b>");
                DT.Columns.Add("<b>Account Group</b>");
            }
            else
            {
                DT.Columns.Add("<b>Acc.Head Code</b>");
                DT.Columns.Add("<b>Account Head</b>");  
            }

                DT.Columns.Add("<b>Debit</b>");
                DT.Columns.Add("<b>Credit</b>");


            for (int j = 0; j < grdTrialBal.VisibleRowCount; j++)
            {
                DataRow DR;
                DR = DT.NewRow();
                if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "2")
                {
                    DR["<b>Sub Group Code</b>"] = grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "ahdUserCode");
                    DR["<b>Account Sub Group</b>"] = grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "ahdname");
                }
                else if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "3")
                {
                    DR["<b>Group Code</b>"] = grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "ahdUserCode");
                    DR["<b>Account Group</b>"] = grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "ahdname");
                }
                else
                {
                    DR["<b>Acc.Head Code</b>"] = grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "ahdUserCode");
                    DR["<b>Account Head</b>"] = grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "ahdname");
                }
                if (Convert.ToDecimal(grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "trnAhdDrAmt")) != 0)
                { 
                 DR["<b>Debit</b>"] = Convert.ToDecimal(grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "trnAhdDrAmt"));
                }
                if (Convert.ToDecimal(grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "trnAhdCrAmt")) != 0)
                {
                 DR["<b>Credit</b>"] = Convert.ToDecimal(grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "trnAhdCrAmt"));
                }



                CrAmount = CrAmount + Convert.ToDecimal(grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "trnAhdCrAmt"));
                DrAmount = DrAmount + Convert.ToDecimal(grdTrialBal.GetRowValues(j, "trnAhdDrAmt"));

                DT.Rows.Add(DR);
            }
            DataRow Dr1;
            Dr1 = DT.NewRow();

            if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "2")
            {
                Dr1["<b>Sub Group Code</b>"] = "";
                Dr1["<b>Account Sub Group</b>"] = "<b>Total</b>";
            }
            else if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "3")
            {
                Dr1["<b>Group Code</b>"] = "";
                Dr1["<b>Account Group</b>"] = "<b>Total</b>";
            }
            else
            {
                Dr1["<b>Acc.Head Code</b>"] = "";
                Dr1["<b>Account Head</b>"] = "<b>Total</b>";
            }

            Dr1["<b>Debit</b>"] = "<b>" + DrAmount.ToString("#0.#0") + "</b>";
            Dr1["<b>Credit</b>"] = "<b>" + CrAmount.ToString("#0.#0") + "</b>";

            DT.Rows.Add(Dr1);

            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

            dg.DataSource = DT;
            dg.DataBind();

            String strFileName = "Trial Balance Account Group Wise.xls";
            if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "2")
            {
                strFileName = "Trial Balance Account Sub Group Wise.xls";
            }
            else if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "3")
            {
                strFileName = "Trial Balance Account Group Wise.xls";
            }
            else
            {
                strFileName = "Trial Balance Account Head Wise.xls";
            }
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            CommonFunctions cf = new CommonFunctions();
            String[] aTo = mskToDate1.Text.Split(new[] { '/', '-' });
            String dTo;
            dTo = aTo[0] + "/" + cf.getMonthName(Convert.ToInt32(aTo[1])) + "/" + aTo[2];

            if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "2")
            {
                htw.WriteLine("<b><u><font size='5'>" + "Trial Balance - Account Sub Group Wise - As on :" + dTo + " </font></u></b>");
            }
            else if (hidType.Get("Type").ToString() == "3")
            {
                htw.WriteLine("<b><u><font size='5'>" + "Trial Balance - Account Group Wise - As on :" + dTo + " </font></u></b>");
            }
            else
            {
                htw.WriteLine("<b><u><font size='5'>" + "Trial Balance - Account Head Wise - As on : " + dTo + " </font></u></b>");
            }

            dg.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();

            dg = null;
            dg.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set  filename in double quotes

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + strFileName+ "\"");
```